# Localization in Identity Server

Tags: localization, identityserver4, openid-connect

I added the shared localization in Identity Server 4 Core 2.2 (https://damienbod.com/2017/11/01/shared-localization-in-asp-net-core-mvc/comment-page-1/#comment-21394).

https://my.domain.com/Account/Register?culure=xx-YY&ui-culture=xx-YY
is working.

Now, how can I pass the culture and iu-culture parameters to my IdendityServer with the OidClient LoginAsync() in the native app?

```
            var options = new OidcClientOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://my.domain.com",
                ClientId = "hybrid",
                ClientSecret = "secret",

                Scope = "openid profile api offline_access",
                ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect,

                RedirectUri = "myscheme://signin-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "myscheme://signout-callback-oidc",

                Browser = new PlatformWebView()
            };

            _client = new OidcClient(options); 

            var result = await _client.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to add support for the OIDC optional parameter called ui_locales.
Damien Bod has a post on this as well: [identityserver4-localization-using-ui_locales-and-the-query-string](https://damienbod.com/2017/11/11/identityserver4-localization-using-ui_locales-and-the-query-string/)

To pass the ui_locales from your client to the identityserver you can use `FrontChannelExtraParameters` property of the `LoginRequest`.

Parameters added to the `FrontChannelExtraParameters` of the `LoginRequest` will be added to the end of the authorize URL.

If you change the last line of your code to this:

```
var result = await _client.LoginAsync(
    new LoginRequest{ FrontChannelExtraParameters = new { ui_locales = "en-US" }} );
```

The authorize request should look something like this:

```
"https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/authorize?response_type=code&nonce=20c640......&ui_locales=en-US"
```